# "how to" questions to Command Line Interface of hunspell

Tags: command-line-arguments, hunspell

mighty All,
may my question are stupid, don't hesitate to estimate how foolish I am, but, tell me please the answers on couple of questions:
intro: 
I've installed hunspel into c:\hunspell dir on Windows7.
hunspell.exe is in c:\hunspell\bin (added to PATH).
Dicts are in c:\hunspell\share\hunspell.
No Open office, Libreoffice, or something like.
Trying to use command:
echo "word-to-spell" | hunspell.exe -d en_US
the questions:
   user dictionary - what it is: the name, path where it must be, how to add 
   session user dictionary - what it is: the name, path where it must be, how to add, how to check if it added to user dict.
I tried some samples, but the program tells me, the word is added to user dict, but the new check offers corrections as the word is not in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:
- user dictionary really is a text file; may have arbitrary name,
preferably name ending with .dic, has an affix dictionary, named as the dic file with .aff extension, encoding UTF-8 mentioned in .aff file, locating in the hunspell ditctionaries dir.
- using static dll under windows not recommended, very time consuming.
- command line interface more productive.
- use command line call for every word to check.
- if you want to add the word to user dictiionary, you must do it yourself, so it will used by the next call for next checking word.

That's all.

Thanks for participating,
Radmir